Is Pilate being portrayed as a "good guy "?
I think that the validity of the Gospel's account regarding the role of Pontius Pilate in the Crusifixion is contestable. One reason is Pilate's own account in Matthew 27:24:

So when Pilate saw that he was gaining nothing, but rather that a
riot was beginning, he took water and washed his hands before the
crowd, saying, “I am innocent of this man’s blood;[2] see to it
yourselves.”

According to the biblical accounts, Jews are condemned for promoting the execution of Jesus Christ on the cross.
However, the Roman Empire was portrayed as the antagonist and Pilate was drawn as playing a good role in all this jazz just because Paul was interested in spreading Christianity all over Rome.

Is there historical evidence that Pilate stole money from the Holy Temple in Israel and invested that money in building an aqueduct?
What historical sources provide information about the money stolen by Pilate?


I tried making the question more clear through my edits, but I still failed at some parts. What sources portray the Roman Empire as an antagonist, while portraying Pilate as a protagonist? What does Pilate have to do with Paul? Also, are you interested in the validity of the biblical account regarding the role of Pilate in the crucifixion or about the money he supposedly stole? It is important here to scope the question otherwise it might get closed.

Yes, I am interested in the validity of the biblical account. Cause Paul was interested in preaching all over the Roman empire, so he could not present romans as enemies, so he presented jews as enemies

The story about Pilato stealing the money is just to illustrate that Pilato was not a mercifull man

Just to prevent misunderstandings: Paul was not the author of the story of the crucifixion. So I am still confused about the relation of Paul to Pilate that seems to be assumed in the question.

I also think the first question that needs to be asked is: Does the Bible portray Pilate as "the good guy"? I don't think that people here agree with the assumption that Pilate was portrayed as a protagonist in the Bible.

But Paul was preaching about Jesus Christ in Rome before the first gospel ,written by Marcos, was released. So he might have influenced that publication

And I consider that the Bible spread the idea that Pilato was not the bad one, maybe also not the good one cause he was a dealer of the Roman empire. But definetively not the bad one cause when it comes to Jesus death. indeed it's said that jews insisted in killing Jesus Christ, refusing to release Barrabas for instance

Well yes the Jews take the responsibility for pressing Pilate into allowing the execution. But Pilate was still responsible for allowing the execution of someone who is innocent. So politically speaking that questions his integrity and justice. Imagine if today someone gets executed or punished because a mob presses the judge into it without evidence of a crime.

I think in general, this question makes too many contestable assumptions. I think you can create a good question for each assumption. Like "Is Pilate being portrayed as a "good guy"? Or: "Did Paul's missionary work, influence the writing of the story of Jesus?"

Thanks a lot Telion, my English is not so good

I think you'll find that Paul was often treated quite harshly throughout the Roman world because of the message he preached.

You're definitely asking two distinct questions here, we don't allow that on the site because if one person answers half of the question well and another person answers another question well, which one do you mark as the accepted answer?

Peter Turner , such a problem has been solved

I am not certain this is the right place to ask your question. I see how it is an interesting question, but as far as I know there are no parts of Christianity where the Bible isn't seen as the word of God.
There can be much debate about a lot, like the matter which books are part of the Bible, what exactly is the significance of the Bible being the word of God.
But what you are asking is to disprove that the Bible was written, at least partially, as a marketing tool for christianity by Paul.
Like I said, that sounds like a reasonable question outside christianity, and it may produce fascinating answers. But I really think most christians would answer to your question about history evidence: it is in the Bible, that is your evidence.

https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/pontius-pilate-and-the-jerusalem-aqueduct/
Here's an article from 2021 connecting the fairly recently discovered aqueduct system from the Beir spring into Jerusalem.
Radiocarbon dating of the plaster involved in its construction makes it very possible that it was built during the time of Pontius Pilate.
The historian Josephus chronicles an uprising that took place as a result of Pilate misappropriating Temple funds.
